# Pressing 0 results in the object continously rotating on its y axis and pressing it again stops it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want the pressing of the button  0 to rotate the entire object on its y axis, and when it keeps doing it until I press 0 again. How can I do this?

This is what I have, but it only works if you hold down 0 not press it once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotateYAxis : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        bool pressed = false;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha0))
            pressed = true;
        if (pressed) { 
            transform.RotateAround(transform.position, (Vector3.up), Time.deltaTime * 90f);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha0))
            {
                pressed = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update is called on every frame, so you need to store some indications of whether the object should rotate or not. Let's call it 'shouldRotate'. Then at the beginning of the **Update** function we check if that state should change or not. After that we rotate if necessary.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotateYAxis : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool shouldRotate = false; //should not rotate at the beginning

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha0)) {
            shouldRotate = !shouldRotate; //changing true to false and false to true
        }
        if (shouldRotate) {
            transform.RotateAround(transform.position, (Vector3.up), Time.deltaTime * 90f);
        }
    }
}
```

NB: I have used the method **GetKeyDown** instead of method **GetKey**. GetKeyDown will only return true in the frame where the key pressed happened the first time. Otherwise the state of 'shouldRotate' would change in every frame while the button is pressed.